# How can delete a polygon on google maps Ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, polygon

I am new with the Native Google Maps API with Cordova using Ionic 3, and I would like to know the way to delete polygons, markers, circles, etc. with a button, for example.

Actually, I have in a method called `loadMap()` the parts to create a polygon and it works. But I would like to be able from another method, like `removePolygon()`, remove the polygon.

My `loadMap()`code is the follows:

```
loadMap() {

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
        camera: {
            target: {
                lat: 39.695263,
                lng: 3.017571
            },
            zoom: 8,
        }
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

    let myPolygonCoord: ILatLng[] = [

        {
            lat: 39.81952717082459,
            lng: 3.1078016219598794
        },
        {
            lat: 39.7794339492445,
            lng: 3.0212842879755044
        },
        {
            lat: 39.66007130788319,
            lng: 3.1476270614130044
        },
        {
            lat: 39.72030660365558,
            lng: 3.2739698348505044
        }
    ];
    let myPolygon: PolylineOptions = {
        'points': myPolygonCoord,
        'strokeColor': '#89c3eb',
        'fillColor': '#89c3eb',
        'strokeWidth': 2
    };

    this.map.addPolygon(myPolygon).then((polygon: Polygon) => {});

}
```

By the other hand, on the method `removePolygon()`:

```
 removePolygon(){
   //how to call the map and remove the polygon? 
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after trying different stuff, I could find a way to solve this.

Declare a variable the one stores the value returned after create the polygon, and after that, just simply use the method remove:

`generalPolygon : any;`

`this.map.addPolygon(myPolygon).then((polygon: Polygon) => {this.generalPolygon = polygon});`

`removePolygon(){
   this.generalPolygon.remove();
 }`

And that's it.